# How to Serialize T type in Json file

Tags: c#, json, generics, serialization

I want to save the information of a model in the Json file I want to implement this in such a way that I can easily store different models So I used this method:

```
 public abstract class SettingBase
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public abstract string Filename { get; }
    
        public static T Load<T>() where T : SettingBase, new()
        {
            T result = new T();
            result = JsonFile.Load<T>(result.Filename) ?? result;    
            return result;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            JsonFile.Save(Filename, this);
        }
    }
```

JsonFile:

```
public static class JsonFile
    {

        public static void Save<T>(string fileName, T @object)
        {
            
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(fileName))
            {
                string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(@object);
                writer.Write(json);
            }
        }

        public static T Load<T>(string fileName)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

now i can use like this:

```
 var xx = SettingBase.Load<AppModel>();
  xx.boo = true;
  xx.integ = 25;
  xx.str = "sss";
  xx.Save();
```

The problem is that the save operation is not performed and nothing is saved in the json file
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is not currently supported on .NET Core Probably supported in .Net 6.0 You must use  newtonsoft.json

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void Save<T>(string fileName, T @object)
    {
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(@object);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, json);
    }

    public static T Load<T>(string fileName)
    {
        var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json)
    }
```

Comment: The same result as before, saving does not work

Comment: are you getting an exception

Comment: I found something interesting if I use the Newton.json library it works without problems but if I use the system.Text.Json in .Net Core it does not work